# Logging is not working while implementing AOP aspect?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, spring-aop

I am trying to implement logging using aspect oriented programming with log4j configuration . My requirement is unique so I am stuck with same technology. Let me know in below code why logging is not working even I can see `System.out.println` giving me appropriate result.

Note: there is no problem with log4j property file its working fine if called independently.

```
package com.test.media.core.logger;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StopWatch;

@Component
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    //private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(LoggingAspect.class);

    @Before("execution(* com.test.media.core.*.*.*(..))")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        Log log = LogFactory.getLog(joinPoint.getClass());
        System.out.println("logBefore is running " +joinPoint.getClass());
        log.debug("medthod  " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName()+"() is hijacked for execution");
        log.debug("******");
    }

    @After("execution(* com.test.media.core.*.*.*(..))")
    public void logAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        log.debug("medthod  " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName()+"() log After execution");
        log.debug("******");

    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.test.media.core.*.*.*(..))", returning = "result")
    public void logAfterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {

        log.debug("medthod  " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName()+"() log After Returning");
        log.debug("Method returned value is : " + result);
        log.debug("******");

    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.test.media.core.*.*.*(..))", throwing = "error")
    public void logAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable error) {

        log.debug("medthod  " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName()+"() is thowing some exception");
        log.debug("Exception : " + error);
        log.debug("******");

    }

    @Around("execution(* com.test.media.core.*.*.*(..))")
    public Object logTimeMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

            StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
            stopWatch.start();

            Object retVal = joinPoint.proceed();

            stopWatch.stop();

            StringBuffer logMessage = new StringBuffer();
            logMessage.append(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName());
            logMessage.append(".");
            logMessage.append(joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
            logMessage.append("(");
            // append args
            Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                logMessage.append(args[i]).append(",");
            }
            if (args.length > 0) {
                logMessage.deleteCharAt(logMessage.length() - 1);
            }

            logMessage.append(")");
            logMessage.append(" execution time: ");
            logMessage.append(stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis());
            logMessage.append(" ms");
            log.debug(logMessage.toString());
            return retVal;
    }
}
```

If anyone has doubt about log4j property file , I am adding it as well.

```
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=D:\\logs\\tool\\tool.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Log everything. Good for troubleshooting
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO

# Log all JDBC parameters
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=ALL
```

Comment: You're using an `execution` pointcut, so chances are `this.getClass()` returns a different class than the one you've intended (probably the aspect class, rather than the 'weaved' class). I'd check if it has the value you expect of it...

Comment: Try private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class)

Comment: @Jango You can see in code snippet I tried it all but no success  .

Comment: @ORiLENTZ I tried with joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName() but no results..

Comment: What is that you have tried and what is 'not working'? Can you add test class too?

Comment: I think somehow aspect call not invoking log4j properties configuration.

Comment: @SheetalMohanSharma if I replace log.debug with sysout it will give me desired result. I dont know why you are looking for test class .

Comment: If you are seeing output in `System.out` then the aspect is working and your log4j config is wrong. YOu probably haven't configured the appropriate logger. Also your case isn't unique Spring provides such an interceptor out-of-the-box, the [`CustomizableTraceInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/CustomizableTraceInterceptor.html).

Comment: @M. Deinum I never said aspect is not working, It's logger which is causing issue somehow. 
I made changes as you requested . Let me know if you find any discrepancy in log4j .

Comment: @virtualBhoot i didnt see the usage of LoggerFactory in the code, try this one Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class)

Comment: @jango I already tried it but no success..

Comment: Your log level is INFO, your aspect is logging at debug so nothing will be printed.

Comment: M. Deinum this is also not the cause .. I changed the level as well but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all suggestions. I got the solution, basically it was not a java code issue. This unknown behavior was occurring due to garbage pom entries. Working pom entries are given below:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```